# Openwhisk serverless setup on premise

Tags: apache, serverless-framework, openwhisk, serverless-architecture

I want to setup apache openwhisk on-premise in my organization. so that we can use it internally within the org. i am not able to find much on the net on this. i tried cloning the code from git and building it in the windows. but it doesn't work. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Follow [these steps](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk#quick-start) to start the platform in a virtual machine in your local environment.

```
# Clone openwhisk
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk.git

# Change directory to tools/vagrant
cd openwhisk/tools/vagrant

# Run script to create vm and run hello action
./hello
```

If this works, you should see the following output.

```
wsk action invoke /whisk.system/utils/echo -p message hello --result
{
    "message": "hello"
}
```

If you encounter problems with these steps, please [open an issue](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues) in the Github repository for the project.

Comment: I was thinking of not using the vagrant and doing a local build and install

Answer (score 0):

Deploy OpenWhisk using the [ansible playbook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/tree/master/ansible#deploying-openwhisk-using-ansible) in high-availability mode.